# trying to do a k-mean algorithm but running into a value error problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, k-means

I am trying to do a k-means algorithm for this Wisconsin Breast Cancer dataset found here:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data

This is the code I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data"
df = pd.read_csv(url, header=None, na_values="?")
df.columns = ['Scn', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7', 'A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'Class']

data = df.drop(columns=['Scn', 'Class'])

np.random.seed()
centroid_indices = np.random.choice(data.index, 2, replace=False)
centroids = data.loc[centroid_indices]
centroids.index = ['mu_2', 'mu_4']

max_iterations = 50
iteration = 0
while iteration < max_iterations:
    distances = pd.DataFrame()
    distances.index = ['mu_2', 'mu_4']
    for centroid_name, centroid in centroids.iterrows():
        distance = ((data - centroid) ** 2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5
        distances[centroid_name] = distance
    df['Predicted_Class'] = np.where(distances['mu_2'] < distances['mu_4'], 2, 4)
    new_centroids = df.groupby('Predicted_Class').mean()
    if new_centroids.equals(centroids):
        break  
    centroids = new_centroids
    iteration += 1
```

I keep getting an error with this code, unfortunately, which is a value error with the line that starts with `df['Predicted_Class']`

This is the precise error:

```py
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (699)
```

I understand why this is happening (my array with distances only has two values in it whereas the main data frame has 699 rows, but I don't exactly know how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
    distances = pd.DataFrame()
    distances.index = ['mu_2', 'mu_4']
```

you've created a 'horizontal' empty dataframe, with no columns, but with row index as ['mu_2', 'mu_4'].

So when you try to write some values into this dataframe `distances[centroid_name] = distance`, the result structure is quite a strange one, if you print it out:

```
      mu_2  mu_4
mu_2   NaN   NaN
mu_4   NaN   NaN
```

What I think you meant to do - is to create a classic 'vertical' dataframe with two columns:

```
while iteration < max_iterations:
    distances = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['mu_2', 'mu_4'])
    
    for centroid_name, centroid in centroids.iterrows():
        distance = ((data - centroid) ** 2).sum(axis=1) ** 0.5
        distances[centroid_name] = distance
    
    df['Predicted_Class'] = np.where(distances['mu_2'] < distances['mu_4'], 'mu_2', 'mu_4')
    
    new_centroids = df.groupby('Predicted_Class').mean()
    
    if new_centroids.equals(centroids):
        break  
    centroids = new_centroids
    iteration += 1
```

This process finishes successfully and predicts some classes:

```
np.unique(df["Predicted_Class"], return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
(array(['mu_2', 'mu_4'], dtype=object), array([464, 235]))
```

Note that I also changed class assigment here
`df['Predicted_Class'] = np.where(distances['mu_2'] < distances['mu_4'], 'mu_2', 'mu_4')`
So that new types of classes (`2`, `4`) are not created and do not confuse the process, because your code depends on `centroid_name`.

Comment: @JosephLarson If this fixes your problem then you accept the answer by clicking the gray check next to the solution.